# Open Source Audio Library In Java

Tags: java, audio

I am looking for an open source audio library similar to BASS from un4seen (http://www.un4seen.com/) to be used in Java applications. Could someone point me to a similar project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't mind using native libraries, OpenAL has at least these two Java wrappers:

- [JOAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenAL)
- [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/)

I have yet to try it myself, but it feels pretty solid as LWJGL, which many games are based on, has chosen to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Try Beads: http://www.beadsproject.net. Available as jar, processing library or Eclipse project.

Answer (score 1):

How about [JSyn](http://www.softsynth.com/jsyn/) ? According to their website, they will release the source code soon.

Another alternative is [FMJ](http://fmj-sf.net/). I actually think this is better than the JSyn which I specified above.

Check out [jAudio](http://jaudio.sourceforge.net/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

JSyn, a modular audio synthesizer, was just released as open source on GitHub under the Apache License V2.

https://github.com/philburk/jsyn

Answer (score 1):

*As of 2015*

FMJ and JAudio are pretty out of date.

JSyn and Beads are good to go.

of the two, JSyn is more popular in Google, but beads has a seemingly more active community.