# How to use Slider for MP3 Audio File Duration in Java?

Tags: java

I want to make an program in Java to play MP3 files. I use JLayer jar to play MP3 Files and mp3agic jar to display mp3 file tags like artist name etc.
One thing I want to ask you all is that how can I use JSlider in my code to 
seek to a duration(time) of my MP3 File using Slider?Also please let me know if I have to use external JARs

Here is the code:

```
import javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException;
import com.mpatric.mp3agic.InvalidDataException;
import com.mpatric.mp3agic.Mp3File;
import com.mpatric.mp3agic.UnsupportedTagException;
import javazoom.jl.player.advanced.*;
import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
public class MP3Player extends JFrame implements ChangeListener{
JFrame f;
JSlider sl;
FileInputStream fis;
AdvancedPlayer pl;
Mp3File mp3tags;
String s;
MP3Player() throws JavaLayerException,IOException, UnsupportedTagException, InvalidDataException
{
    f=new JFrame();
    f.setTitle("MP3 Player");
    f.setBounds(250, 150, 500, 500);
FileDialog fd=new FileDialog(f,"Select Audio File",FileDialog.LOAD);
fd.setVisible(true);
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(new File(fd.getDirectory(),fd.getFile()));
pl=new AdvancedPlayer(fis);
s=fd.getDirectory()+fd.getFile();
mp3tags=new Mp3File(s);
System.out.println(mp3tags.getId3v2Tag().getArtist());
new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
        try {
            pl.play();
        } catch (JavaLayerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}.start();
sl=new JSlider();
sl.setBounds(250, 500, 500, 500);
f.add(sl);
sl.setMinimum(0);
sl.setValue(0);
sl.addChangeListener(this);
}
public static void main(String asrar[]) throws JavaLayerException,IOException, UnsupportedTagException, InvalidDataException
{
    MP3Player mp3=new MP3Player();
    mp3.f.setVisible(true);
}
@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

}
}
```

Comment: So you are just asking for the code in your `stateChanged`? Do you need to know how to get a value from the silder, ie getValue(), or how to convert that value to a time? Or how to seek to that time with the Mp3File?

Comment: I'm asking how to seek to that time with MP3File.

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to know how many frames are in your file, and the total duration of those frames.

```
int totalFrames = mp3Tags.getFrameCount();
long timeInMillis = mp3Tags.getLengthInMilliseconds();
```

Once we have that, there are a number of things that can be done. You can set the maximum value of your slider.

```
sl.setMaximumValue(totalFrames);
```

Then when you move the slider, you you have your player play from that point.

```
@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    int value = ((JSlider)e.getSource()).getValue();
    pl.play(value, totalFrames); #or Integer.MAX_VALUE to play to end for certain.
}
```

A javafx way would be to use the Media/MediaPlayer.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.nio.file.Paths;

/**
 * Created by melkor on 7/30/17.
 */
public class PlayMediaFx extends Application {
    MediaPlayer player;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Pane pane = new VBox();

        Button button = new Button("play");
        button.setOnMouseClicked(evt->{
            if(player==null){
                loadSound();
            }
            player.play();
        });

        Button seek = new Button("seek 3 seconds");
        seek.setOnMouseClicked(evt->{
            if(player!=null){
                Duration d = player.getCurrentTime();
                player.seek(d.add(new Duration(3000)));
            }
        });

        Button pause = new Button("pause");
        pause.setOnMouseClicked(evt->{
            if(player!=null){

                player.pause();
            }
        });

        Button stop = new Button("stop");
        stop.setOnMouseClicked(evt->{
            if(player!=null){
                player.stop();
            }
        });

        pane.getChildren().addAll(button, pause, seek, stop);
        root.getChildren().addAll(pane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void loadSound(){
        Media media = new Media(Paths.get("test.aif").toUri().toString());
        player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        player.setOnReady(()->{
            player.setStopTime(player.getTotalDuration());
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This has all of the ingredients except for the Slider.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: I tried your method, but when I seek it throws me ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: And also I want to make the slider move as the music plays forward. So how can I do that?

Comment: Can you seek to any value, check the numbers you are passing to `play`? Have you considered using the javafx [MediaPlayer](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html)? It seems to have a better API.

Comment: Ok, may I know which formats does javafx MediaPlayer supports?

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) shows quite a few codecs that are supported.

Comment: But I don't know how to use Advanced Player. Can you please give me some sample?

Comment: @AsrarBashirSunge Okay, I created a small example in javafx. It has all of the ingredients but no slider. Really I would be writing the whole thing from scratch at this point, so you should create something and then as for help on it. Here is an example also https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/playercontrol.htm

Comment: Do you have an better API than this for Java Sound that plays mp3s?

Comment: What's wrong with this one? Here is a thread with some suggestions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999629/open-source-audio-library-in-java